# How do I dump the TCP client's buffer in order to accept more data?

Tags: python, tcp

I've got a simple TCP server and client. The client receives data:

```
received = sock.recv(1024)
```

It seems trivial, but I can't figure out how to recieve data larger than the buffer. I tried chunking my data and sending it multiple times from the server (worked for UDP), but it just told me that my pipe was broken.

Suggestions?

Comment: So, what, are you only calling `recv()` once and then closing the socket?

Comment: Yep. That's it. But that is the problem, as you noted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no idea how much data is going to pour over the socket, and you simply want to read everything until the socket closes, then you need to put `socket.recv()` in a loop:

```
# Assumes a blocking socket.
while True:
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    if not data:
        break
    # Do something with `data` here.
```

Comment: That was it! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is the one you're looking for, but that's not a situation you want to find yourself in.   You should develop an over-the-wire protocol that uses a fixed-length field that describes how much data is going to be sent.  It's a [Type-Length-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) protocol, which you'll find again and again and again in network protocols. It future-proofs your protocol against unforeseen requirements and helps isolate network transmission problems from programmatic ones.

The sending side becomes something like:

```
socket.write(struct.pack("B", type)         #send a one-byte msg type 
socket.write(struct.pack("H", len(data))    #send a two-byte size field
socket.write(data)
```

And the receiving side something like:

```
type = socket.read(1)                                 # get the type of msg
dataToRead = struct.unpack("H", socket.read(2))[0]    # get the len of the msg
data = socket.read(dataToRead)                        # read the msg

if TYPE_FOO == type:
    handleFoo(data)

elif TYPE_BAR == type:
    handleBar(data)

else:
    raise UnknownTypeException(type)
```

You end up with an over-the-wire message format that looks like:

```
struct {
     unsigned char type;
     unsigned short length;
     void *data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that:

- Your operating system has it's own idea of what it's TCP/IP socket buffer size is.
- TCP/IP packet maximum size (generally is 1500 bytes)
- pydoc for socket suggests that 4096 is a good buffer size

With that said, it'd really be helpful to see the code around that one line. There are a few things that could play into this, if you're using select or just polling, is the socket non-blocking, etc.

It also matters how you're sending the data, if your remote end disconnects. More details.

Comment: I didn't include the rest because it really wasn't relevent. I was literally just receiving the data and then saving it to a file -- but of course the buffer was limiting it so the output was always cut off.